# Простое копирование из INPUT

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно копировать поля в форме.

Есть

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Собственник ФИО</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="sobstv_fio" id="sobstv_fio"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();"   class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Паспорт (серия и номер)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="passport" id="passport"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport" maxlength="12" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата выдачи паспорта</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="passport_date" id="passport_date"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
        </div>
```

и

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Страхователь ФИО</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="strah_fio" id="strah_fio"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control" maxlength="255" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="date2" id="date2"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Паспорт (серия и номер)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="passport2" id="passport2"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_passport" maxlength="12" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Дата выдачи паспорта</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="passport_date2" id="passport_date2"  onkeyup="check();" onkeypress="check();" onchange="check();" class="form-control mask_date" maxlength="10" required>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Нужно что бы при клике на чекбокс

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleCheckbox(this)"> 
            </label>
```

данные из формы первой части копировались во вторую.
Начал делать так, но почемуто копируеться только первое поле

```js
 <script>  
  function toggleCheckbox()
 {
 strah_fio.value=propiska2.value
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: в скрипте менял ID на другие поля они не работают!

Comment: Что мешает в функции прописать все пары Id? function toggleCheckbox()
{
 strah_fio.value = sobstv_fio.value;
 passport_date2.value = passport_date.value;
 passport2.value = passport.value;
 date2.value = date1.value;
}

Comment: @roman-stoliarenko спасибо, сейчас заработало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб ставилось и снималось можно так. И вместо пачкии обработчиков на инпутах можно установить oninput, хотя я не вникал что они там делают :)

```
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
</label>
```

JS

```
(function Init() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("check");
  if (checkbox.addEventListener) {
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", OnChangeCheckbox, false);
  }
})();

function OnChangeCheckbox(event) {
  var checkbox = event.target;
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    strah_fio.value = sobstv_fio.value;
    passport_date2.value = passport_date.value;
    passport2.value = passport.value;
    date2.value = date1.value;
  } else {
    strah_fio.value = '';
    passport_date2.value = '';
    passport2.value = '';
    date2.value = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо)
Я не силен в js так что костылей наворотил) но вроде пока катит, если что потом буду разбираться, а то сроки жмут(